# Okta App Accessing issues

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

I have added community applications to our Dashboard by clicking on Add Apps(home page), and assigned to the people. its working fine, people able to access Community Software, but whenever we are intended to create our custom app(Jive demo sandbox) from admin panel and assigned people its not working as expected. even the admin not able to access the app it is showing message "Sorry, you can't access Jive Software because you are not assigned this app in Okta".

i have followed the integration process from

http://developer.okta.com/use_cases/integrate_with_okta/

please help me that i am missing any integrations or configurations

Answer (score 0):

There is not sufficient information in this question to be able to answer.  Have you tried reaching out to [Okta Support](https://support.okta.com/help)?  They should be able to check your configuration with your permission and help you with it.